# "Due diligence" in Portuguese

Tags: tradução-inglês, tradução

Before a bank takes on a new customer, they do "due diligence" and "Know your customer" checks to ensure that the bank is not laundering money. When a company takes on a new partner, customer, or supplier, it may also do "due diligence". I believe this is a legal term.

What is the equivalent in Portuguese?

Comment: The [main suggestion](https://www.linguee.pt/ingles-portugues/traducao/due+diligence.html) on Lingee is "devida diligência" or to keep the original English term, but let's see if one of our contributors with better legal knowledge posts an answer.

Comment: O termo em inglês “Due Diligence” pode ser traduzido para o português como **diligência prévia** e refere-se ao processo de estudo, análise e a avaliação detalhada de informações de uma Empresa alvo da negociação, geralmente chamada de Target, visando a identificação de eventuais distorções relevantes, decorrentes das práticas empresariais.https://www.contabeis.com.br/artigos/4523/afinal-o-que-e-a-due-diligence/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term *due diligence* is commonly used in English, but it may be translated as *diligência*, *diligência devida* or *diligência prévia*.

From [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/dilig%C3%AAncia), the closest definition of *diligência* for *due diligence* is:

> 4. Busca, pesquisa, averiguação.

Translation: Search, research, enquiry.

---

Some examples of the use of the term I found on the Internet, in the context of legal verification, verification of suppliers or other involved parties:

> - **Due diligence** financeira e legal (p. 11)
> - [...] pela realização da **diligência (due diligence)** sobre as informações da empresa que serão utilizadas na elaboração dos documentos de emissão [...] (p. 15)
>
> <sub>Source: [B3](https://www.b3.com.br/data/files/5C/71/2C/ED/36BD4710A4F37D47AC094EA8/custos-abertura-capital-Brasil-2020.pdf). This document has a glossary explaining the english term.</sub>

> Em 2019, foram iniciadas atividades de **Due Diligence** Integrada de Fornecedores, no Banco do Brasil.
>
> <sub>Source: [Banco do Brasil](https://www.bb.com.br/pbb/pagina-inicial/compras,-contratacao-e-venda-de-imoveis/fornecedores/etica-e-integridade#/).</sub>

> O que é **Due Diligence**?
> Esse termo em inglês significa "**diligência devida**" ou "**diligência prévia**". [...]
>
> <sub>Source: [Neoway](https://blog.neoway.com.br/due-diligence/).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

The term equivalent to "due diligence" and often used in Portuguese is "***diligência prévia***", which refers to the process of investigating a business opportunity that the investor must accept in order to assess the risks of the transaction. Although such an investigation can be done under a legal obligation, the term usually refers to voluntary investigations.

In the literal translation to Portuguese, *"due/devida"* has the meaning of debit, owing, payable, overdue. So, in the current vernaculum, the expression *"devida diligência"* would not make so much sense, since ***"prévia"*** refers to something that is done in advance, before the neuralgic event, which in this case would be the business after the investigation. However, it can be used.

Comment: It is actually incorrect to say that "devida" is only related to debt, since it [can also mean](https://dicionario.priberam.org/devido) "necessário, apropriado" as in "com os devidos cuidados" ("taking the appropriate precautions").

Comment: @stafusa I did not mention, at any time, this mismanagement that “devida” has only that meaning - I even mentioned that it could be used, however, it would not make as much sense as “prévia”, an act that occurs, a priori, from the neuralgic point. On the contrary, I elucidated, using the current vernacular, the premise of the aforementioned term, as a support.

Comment: @stafusa In this sense, “devida” would have this meaning, since, according to the Latin etymology of its verb (debere), comprising from its original conception the idea of ​​obligation and commitment acquired and extended to the ethical and moral conscience into individuald responsibilities, formed by the prefix "de-", in function of deprivation, and the verb "habere", for having, as the root of the infinitive to exist.

Comment: @stafusa So the influence of the prefix "de-", at a private level, as well as it is also guided by the "des-" component, noting that it expresses other interpretations according to the construction and the context, so it includes: “débito” (in Latin debitum), “detrator” (seen in Latin forms detractoris), or “delimitar” (in Latin delimitare).

Comment: @stafusa In addition, as data maxima venia, “diligência prévia” already appeared in the legal writings of Portugal in the 19th century, as seen in the ["Official Collection of Portuguese Legislation", of 1854](http://www2.senado.leg.br/bdsf/handle/id/518674).

Comment: Exatamente: https://qbb.adv.br/artigos/due-diligence/ nada tem a ver com devida nesse caso.

Comment: [The current vernacular]

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent would be:

> devida diligência

or:

> diligência devida

The word *devida*, in this case, has the meaning (according to *Houaiss*):

> que ou o que é objeto [...] de uma obrigação

**Translation:** that which is the object of an obligation

An example of this usage is:

> recebeu-a com a devida consideração

**Translation:** received it with (the) due consideration.

Comment: Since the answer is in English, it would probably be good to add a translation of the quoted Houaiss entry.

Comment: @stafusa. OK. Translations added.